# In Waterfall dialog i am getting "unhandled error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" when returning prompt

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots

```js
async feedbackStep(stepContext) {
    return await stepContext.prompt(CHOICE_PROMPT, {
      prompt: "Please enter your mode of transport.",
      choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices([
        { value: "my vehicle", synonyms: ["car", "truck"] },
        { value: "public transporation", synonyms: ["bus", "shuttle"] },
        { value: "slowly", synonyms: ["walk", "bicycle"] },
      ]),
    });
  }
```

**The Prompt question is also shown in bot. when it comes to choiceFactor.toChoices it throws the error.**

Comment: If the values provided are not strings (like yours) then an action is expected to be present. https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/choices/choiceFactory.ts#L279  Have you tried adding an action to each of the choices?